# Testflight provides old build, after expiring the old build the app disappeared from Testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

I can't update Testflight build for external testing. I uploaded a new build and added it to the group with external testers. The status of old build (3) is "Testing", the status of new one (4) is "Ready to test". When adding the build to the group I unchecked "automatically notify testers" box. Then I opened my Testflight, but no new build appeared. I clicked "Resend invite" near my email on iTunesConnect and got an invite. However, there was an invite for old build (3) with the icon in email from even older build (2). After expiring the old build (3) on iTunesConnect, the app disappeared from my Testflight on the phone. When trying to redeed I get a message "you've already accepted the invite for this app". The status of the build in iTunesConnect is "Ready to test".

Comment: Have you change the version number before update on testflight ?

Comment: no, version number is the same

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem with our app. Looks like something has been broken in TestFlight backend within the last 4 days or so. Previously updating the build worked fine.

Comments from May 16 and later in this thread confirm it's a common issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5802

Comment: Another issue I'm experiencing is that testers don't receive invites. And no option to resend an invite.

Comment: Yes, same with us. We have contacted the support team and they replied they were aware about the issue and were working on resolution.